# Python: How to declare a global array of zeros depending on the input of the user?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, initialization, global-variables

For my program, the user can input a particular n.

Depending on that n, I need to create a global array with n buckets of size zero since I need to use this array in other functions + increment the elements in the bucket, which is again dependent on some conditions.

```
inv = []   # global var counts all inversion at level n
order = [] # global var counts all ordered elements at level n

def foo():
    # Using order and inv here 

def main():
    # Save Input in variable in n
    n = int(raw_input())
    order = [0]*n
    inv = [0]*n
```

How can I do that? I always get an IndexError telling me that list index is out of range. Thanks!

Comment: In your example `n` is a list - I assume you meant `n = int(raw_input())` ?

Comment: @Roukanken yes sorry, I firstly had n, m = map(int, raw_input().split()) - I wanted to simplify the problem, however I forgot about that! Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this - globals vs. arguments.

Using the global keyword allows you to access the global instance of `order` and `inv` within a function.

```
inv = []   # global var counts all inversion at level n
order = [] # global var counts all ordered elements at level n

def foo():
  # Using order and inv here
  global order
  global inv


def main():
  global order
  global inv
  # Save Input in variable in n
  n = map(int, raw_input().split())
  order = [0]*n
  inv = [0]*n
```

The way I would recommend doing it is to declare `order` and `inv` within your main function and then pass them as arguments to the `foo()` or any other function that needs them.

```
def foo(list_order, list_inv):
  # Using order and inv here

def main():
  # Save Input in variable in n
  n = map(int, raw_input().split())
  order = [0]*n
  inv = [0]*n
  foo(order, inv)
```

Comment: Thanks @mattdonders! 1. Is the global order different from the order without the global in the main function? 2. Do I always need to indicate global in my functions if I want to access my global variables?

Comment: @AndrejCoding not sure I understand question #1 about global order. But in regards to #2 - yes if you want to reference a global instance of a variable inside a function you need to use the `global` keyword, otherwise it assumes you want the local instance.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I meant global array named "global order" different from the "order" without the global indicator in the main function. But, I guess it is. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: It's not actually named `global order` its a keyword + variable_name that lets the Python interpreter to use the global instance of that variable (even if you are within a function). Anything defined at the module level (outside of all functions) is automatically part of the global variables.